# Creating .BAK file from SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, database-backups, database-restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup SQL Server via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664869/backup-sql-server-via-c-sharp)

I have a Windows Forms project which is storing some values in SQL Server 2008 R2, I have many tables in there which deals with my application.

I would like to take a database backup so that if the user is to loose the operating system and reinstall, they can restore the database using the backup (.BAK file).

I would like to know how I can take a backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 with C#, and if it's compulsory to install SQL Server in the client computer whilst taking the backup.

Also, how can I restore it? Any examples may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install the client tools.

What you'll need is SMO (Sql Server Management Objects)

This provides an api to perform certain Sql Server tasks including backups

Comment: what about the backups and restore? Can you provide me an example. I am newbie to c#, example can help,
please if you can

Comment: @aquibRocks checkout this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13755/SMO-Manage-your-SQL-Server the examples include backup and other tasks